# How to make a bot to forward a message along with an inline keyboard

Tags: python-3.x, bots, telegram-bot, telebot

Please help me, I started studying Python, I want to write a bot in a telegram, and I want the bot to forward a message from the user along with an inline keyboard, tell me how to do it?

I thought it would work like this, but a mistake:

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])

def all_messages(message):
bot.forward_message(to_chat_id, message.chat.id, message.message_id, reply_markup=markup)

```
#Inline keyboard
markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButtom("Yes", callback_data='good')
item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButtom("Incorrectly filled", callback_data='good')
item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButtom("No", callback_data='bad')



markup.add(item1, item2, item3)
```

The error is this:

> NameError: name 'markup' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible!
Inline buttons can't perform such a thing, but you can let the user sharing something, using url buttons:

> https://t.me/share/url?url=You_can_have_a_url_here&text=Your_text_here

---

Also check the `InlineKeyboardButtom`, is it buttom or button?